# git alias using $((LINES / 2))

Tags: git, alias

I have tried roughly 30 variants of this, including `sh -c` versions, double and single quotes, nested quotes, etc. What am I missing?

```
shortlog = "!git log -n $((LINES / 2))"
```

Comment: What if you work with `bash` instead of `sh`? Perhaps you better use two commands

Comment: Do you mean make a bash alias instead of a git alias?

Comment: oh you try to make an alias. That wasn't clear.

Comment: It's in the title and the tags :)

Comment: I've provided a solution using a function... Does this work? There is probably a one-liner available, but since you want to define an alias, I don't see the point to minimize it...

Comment: git has already a `shortlog` command

Comment: @hek2mgl: indeed (looked it up in the manual), but the question is still useful: how to use environment variables in git aliasses.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out by accident and was confused by the output :) I'm not actually using `shortlog`. I'm using `las`, but I didn't feel like explaining why. It's unimportant.

Comment: @GaryFixler: it should work now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't *love* how I finally got this to work, but it's literally the only thing that's worked at all, and I want this to be over. I removed everything relating to the shorter log aliases from my `~/.gitconfig`, and in my `~/scripts` folder - which is in my `$PATH` - I made files with names like `git-las` (list all short), with code like this in each:

```
#!/bin/bash

$height=$(tput lines)
$height=$((height / 3))
git la -$height
```

I made each executable. Git will take `git las` and find `git-las` (no extension) on my path, if its executable, and execute it, and it works. That `git la` (list all) is in my `~/.gitconfig`, and is just the typical `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate` everyone gives their own name to. This is the *only* thing that works, after easily 100 variations on every bit of online info I could find. Even trying to move the `tput` stuff back into `~/.gitconfig` fails, and `$LINES` also fails in these working files; it's always 0.

What a battle, but now I have short logs (a few different sizes and settings) that scale dynamically with the window to always give me roughly 1/2 to 1/4 oneline log output - dividing by 3 (and 6 for 1/4) accounts for some extra space around merge commits and tricky branch pathways. I've had these hard-coded for a year, but now I'm starting to properly version and share my dotfiles between machines, so I wanted it dynamic for all my different monitor heights, and so it would work in an expected fashion no matter how big I had the window.

Answer (score 1):

What if you define a function?

```
function shortlog { tmp=$(($LINES / 2)); git log -n "$tmp"; }
```

then export it:

```
export -f shortlog
```

You should put it in your `.bashrc` I guess if you want to use it each time you start a terminal (but you can first try it on a isolated sterminal of course).

---

**EDIT**:

does this help?

```
git config alias.shortlog '!f() { tmp=$(($LINES / 2)); git log -n "$tmp"; }; f'
```

Comment: That gets it done, but I'm looking for a way to keep it in .gitconfig. I don't want to have to deploy a .gitconfig and a .bashrc just for this helper alias.

Comment: Updated answer? However, currently I cannot test it :(. Please note that using `git config` is actually only a wrapper to rewrite `.gitconfig` automatically. There is no "real" difference in effect between them.

Comment: Yeah, I always update `.gitconfig` manually. You have an extra $ in front of `LINES`, but even without that, it doesn't work. I can't get variations to work either. Inlining $tmp, removing the quote from $tmp, swapping quotes both ways... either things fail, or nothing is printed.

Comment: Oops. What happens if you use single quotes (modified answer)... At my linux machine, that does the trick...

Comment: Doesn't work here. I copy/pasted your code, but running it (with a different alias name than `shortlog`, because that interferes with the name in git) gives me this error: `f() { tmp=$(($LINES / 2)); git log -n "$tmp"; }; f: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " / 2"`